# Google map full height in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a page with Google Maps frame that occupies whole screen, but I also need a sticky footer at the bottom (where I can place button/icons).

I would like to have my layout based on Bootstrap 3, it should be responsive.
Can you point me to the right direction?

I do not post any code because the one I am working on is useless.

Comment: There are tons of ways to do this. Just render the google api in your container (div within it) and use later on a new container and row to add your footer with a fixed position

Comment: If I knew how to do it I wouldn't ask here :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created a most basic example for you: http://jsbin.com/fazah/3/

Comment: Well, the maps should occupy all height.

Comment: add in the css then `height: 100%;`

Comment: I have updated my answer. It now should be full height in Firefox, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on googles website they have a wonderful API for drop-in google maps.  I've used it with bootstrap and it works fine (you can still edit it's height/width, border, ect.)  Check it out here...

https://developers.google.com/maps/

As for the bottom footer did you try playing with the css for layering already?